# I need a NAS solution with conflicting requirements

Tags: hard-disk, ssd, nas, raid

I have to buy a NAS storage, with a set of simultaneous opposite requirements. In particular, high speed, lots of space and small budget.

Can I do something like:
- Use a NAS with four bays, two for large HDD, and two for fast SSD.
- Set up a RAID just for the two HDD.
- Set up a separate RAID just for the two SSD (if needed).

Is this a feasible configuration?

Can I buy a single NAS solution to be used for both high performance and large data storage?

These are a few numbers to quantify my requirements:
- NAS: 4 bays, 10 Gb Ethernet, Thunderbolt 3.
- HDD: 2, 10 TB each, 7200 rpm, SATA.
- SSD: 2, 1 TB each, SATA.

The drives are going to be purchased separately from the NAS.

Budget: £2600.

Purpose: store and read video from multiple cameras in real-time.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot help with RAID Configurations here. [Super User](https://superuser.com/) might be able to help, but please make sure the check out their [help center](https://superuser.com/help) first.

Comment: I see you have edited your question. Great! But now we need to know a few more details. What configurations do you need this to support? What does "lots of space" mean? Same with "small budget". Can you define these for us? Also, are you going to be purchasing the drives separately, or are you expecting the NAS device to come with them? What are the measurable goals of the device? High speed can mean different things for different people. If you can give us hard numbers, we can reopen this question.

Comment: If you build, as cybernard suggests, as an OS at least look into UnRaid. I have it set up with a 2 x HDD "array" and 2 x SSD "cache". When you copy data to the Nas, it goes initially onto your cache for speed, then depending on the setting on which "share" it was copied to, it moves it to the array (during low use/overnight) for long term storage. (With VMs and your budget, it could even become your main PC.) For your interest: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAy9N1vX76o an actual setup used for heavy video editing. summary @17 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The drives will be purchased separately from the NAS.

I suggest your better off building a PC.

Use a NAS with four bays, two for large HDD, and two for fast SSD

Case with 3  5.25 bays are easy to come by.  I have a SSD enclosure that fits into a 5.25 bay that holds 4 SSD.  Also using 2x 5.25 bays you can easily have room for 2 or even 3 regular hdd.

2 hdd per raid limits you to striping or mirroring and some motherboards have built in controllers which can handle these modes easily.

pcie card for 10gb, you can even have a dual or quad card.
pcie card for thunderbolt.

Even if you go crazy your budget makes this project easy.

$800 for amd x1800, 16gb, and asus x370-pro (which even has a M.2 ssd port for 2gb/s)
$200 for a case,psu, removeable hdd enclosure and ssd 4x in 5.25bay

$150 for a slight older intel dual 10gb card

$600 for an adaptec 7805(or similar) raid controller.(because I got money to burn)

https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboard-Accessory/ThunderboltEX-3/
$79  https://www.cdw.com/product/ASUS-ThunderboltEX-3-Thunderbolt-adapter/4259577?cm_cat=GoogleBase&cm_ite=4259577&cm_pla=NA-NA-ASU_IN&cm_ven=acquirgy&ef_id=WdOaEAAAAIMrZiAP:20180323201802:s&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-cfe9KGD2gIVD4rICh2-WguNEAkYASABEgLEaPD_BwE&s_kwcid=AL!4223!3!198553132221!!!g!315976140630!

$100 for any low end video card

---

Still have money left, party time.